# How to compare multiple objects and sort by criteria priorities in MongoDb mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently working back-end service in node.js using *mongoose* and *express*
It's a kind of game that makes match users. But there are some priorities of the matching process.

- Criteria 1: If users haven't matched within 60 days, and not in the
  same city.
- Criteria 2: If users haven't matched within 60 days, and
  they are in the same city.
- Criteria 3: If users haven't matched
  within 30 days, and they are not in the same city.

.
.
.

it goes like that. The matching process should prioritize criteria 1 and after that criteria 2,3,4,5... It should optimize the matching process.

User Schema

```
    const userSchema = new Schema({
userName: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
  city: { type: String, required: true },
 ,
});
```

Game Schema

```
   const userSchema =  new Schema({
  userIds: { type: Array, required: true }, // Array of user id that is matched, takes 2 user id
  created_time: { type: Date, default: new Date() },
  finished_time: { type: Date, required: true }, 

});
```

Currently, it is handled by a bunch of code that queries each user that has a game with other user but it takes a longer time and not efficient if I need to compare above 100 users.